# jQuery submit immidiate form hangs both Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

form doesnt exist in a DOM, its created on the fly and then submitted

```
$('<form action="http://www.google.com/" method=POST></form>').submit();
```

this simple line causes both browsers to hang (Mozilla even gives a window to terminate script, with error 'too much recursion'), jQuery 1.4.2, havent tried in IE

any ideas?

the original idea was to write a simple jQuery plugin that accepts url and bunch of params in a map, creates a form and submits it as POST..in a non ajaxy way (important) and navigates away from that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the DOM first.

```
$(function() {
    $('<div style="display: none;">'
       + '<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">'
       + '<input type="hidden" name="q" value="jquery" />'
       + '</form></div>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .submit();   
});
```

Comment: It is not necessary to append it to the DOM.

Comment: @Darin - tried it both ways. only seems to work in FF for me when added to the DOM.

Comment: @tvanfosson, you are totally correct. I've tested it on Google Chrome and it worked, so I wrongly assumed this would be the case for all browsers. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @tvanfosson adding to the DOM didnt help still hangs my Firefox

Comment: @user272924, to what action are you posting?

Comment: action is "/", the root of the same  website

Comment: @user272924, that's your problem. You are posting to the same page which posts to itself which posts to itself which posts to itself ... which hangs your browser.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, it hangs regardless of what action i put. second of all / istnt the same page i'm posting from, third of all its not a $(document).ready(.. function so it wont cause it to run again on submit

Comment: @user - then you likely have some other problem.  The code in my example works for me in FF, Opera, and IE (8).

Comment: regardless of action it hangs.. i can paste the entire script. i'm under ubuntu though however dont think it makes a difference

Comment: @user272924, yes please post the entire script as clearly the problem is something else because the script shown here worked for me (posting to google.com).

Comment: @tvanfosson does it navigate you away from the current page??

Comment: @user - note that it's important to have it run in the `ready` function as the body element may not be available to append to until the document ready event happens.  I had omitted that bit from my example, but I've updated it.

Comment: <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            $("<form></form>").attr({action:'/',method:'post'}).appendTo('body').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<button id='btn'>click</button>

Comment: @user - that works for me using action `http://www.google.com/search` and method `get`. I did add the hidden input `q` as well `.append( ... ).appendTo('body')` but no problems.  See http://jsbin.com/afiri3

Comment: @tvanfosson found the answer - submit() needs to be replaced by trigger('submit');

Comment: @user -- hmmm.  what version of jQuery?  if you check my jsbin code using the latest version, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: i think its a matter of doctype or something as when i copy the script locally ina stripped version of jsbin html its stops working

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure **not** to submit to a page which itself constructs a form and submits or the recursion might appear. Here's an example of searching on stackoverflow:

```
$(document.createElement('form'))
    .attr('action', 'http://stackoverflow.com/search')
    .attr('method', 'post')
    .append(
        $(document.createElement('input'))
            .attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', 'q')
            .val('jquery submit form')
    )
.appendTo('body')    
.submit();
```